# ionic ng-cordova vibrate plugin not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am new to ionic and cordova this vibrate plugin is not working.
Can you please point out the error?

This is index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
```

This is app.js in js folder:

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

ionicApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaVibration)) {

    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $cordovaVibration.vibrate(100).then(function() {
                console.log("Phone vibrating");
            })

        });

    }

}

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

I have added `ng-cordova` vibrate plugin.

Comment: Any chance you can toss out more debug information for us? If you are on Android, messages from logcat, or if running 4.4+ from the chrome devtools.

Comment: It is giving following java-script errors.
     Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaVibrationsProvider 
    at ionic.bundle.js:8762
    at ionic.bundle.js:12696
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:12843)
    at ionic.bundle.js:12701
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:12843)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:12875)
    at extend.instance (ionic.bundle.js:17153)
    at ionic.bundle.js:16399
    at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:9030)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:16398)

Comment: Do you have updated versions of ngCordova and Ionic? And does your app have the permissions for vibrate? And your `AndroidManifest.xml` must have permissions for vibrate: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

Comment: I installed this plugin into my Ionic current project and ran it on the iphone 6 without any problems.  did you install the plugin using: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration?  Another thing is the vibration plugin doesn't use promises so putting .then() after vibrate() doesn't do anything.

Comment: Got this working.
Thanks a lot everyone.

I created a working example in the github repository. 

https://github.com/manvick/vibration

Comment: Where was the problem? Now I'm comparing my project with yours and can't find difference. Ofcourse your is running and mine not.

Comment: david Slavik check this working example of vibration plugin.
 https://github.com/manvick/vibration
Or send me your code at manvick95@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

I Had same Problems, mine was solved adding the Cordova Plugin, seems you alredy took care of that: Here are my differences with your Project:

---

I Used this version of platform Ready

```
    $scope.toggle = function() {
      document.addEventListener( "deviceready", function() {
           $cordovaVibration.vibrate( 2000 ); }, false );
    };
```

---

My ionic App definition I placed ngCordova hookup first. Although this may not be an issue

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('starter', ['ngCordova','ionic' ])
```

---

What solves the issue for me was installing the plugin correctly: Try:

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration
```

instead of the official site which says:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration
```

---

I added the permission to /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xm. Although this seems not be necessary because I believe ionic build or ionic run discover you are using vibration and add it for yourself

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing on a device, be sure that the device is un-muted. Many (most) devices will "mute" the vibration as well as the audio. If you are debugging in the browser, you should see 'Vibrating for Xms.' in the console where "X" is the number of milliseconds you supplied to the vibrate function. This tells you the plugin is working (obviously you can't vibrate your computer). But, again, when testing on a device, be sure it's not on mute.